# How to create folders in NetBeans for organizational purposes?

Tags: java, netbeans, organization

Like in Visual Studio: Stand on the solution->Add->New Folder->Drag and Drop classes or whatever into the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Netbeans you can add a **Folder** in the end this folder will be represented like a **package** so what you should to do :

**Source Package > New > Folder > name-of-folder**

[image]

Then you can create your class in it.

If you use point in your name for example `com.folder` this will create two folders in your project, but it represented like one in your project.